# How to dynamically use checkbox to get data from mysql? - jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql, checkbox

I am new to jquery and php but I am trying to use a checkbox to grab stuff from a mysql database.

To further explain, I want a checkbox and when checked it will place the id of the checkbox in a mysql query and display the results from the database.

So, if I check off this box:

```
<input name="apple" type="checkbox" id="apple" /><label for="apple">Apple</label>
```

It will send the id or class name (apple) to the php sql query and gather the results.

I am not entirely sure how to do this so if someone can help that would be great thanks.

**EDIT**

I have a php query that looks like this:

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM explore WHERE category='apple' ORDER BY category";
```

That query just displays the category with 'apple'

I'm not sure how to go from jquery to php by passing the id's for the query. How do I get the id of the checkbox to go into the php page for the "category=  "?

Comment: Do you have any code created? Do you have a existing connection to your database? Did you build yoru database? Tell us where you are at so we can begin to help.

Answer (score 1):

You should be thinking somewhere along the lines of following code...

First you might want to add a class "checked" to your checkboxes like this.

```
<input name="apple" type="checkbox" id="apple" class="checked" />
```

Now for the jquery code...

```
$("input.checked").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/getData.php?id=' + $(this).attr("id"), // the id gets passed here
    success: function(data) {
      alert('Load was performed.'); // Play with your response here
    }
  });
});
```

1. On click event of any input with class "checked", this event will be fired.
2. The id of clicked checkbox will be sent to a server side code, in this case getData.php
3. You will place the mysql query inside the getData.php, then you will send a formatted response, maybe some xml
4. Using ajax, the response will be fetched
5. Then you can manipulate the response as you like